# EaselJS way to change default pivot?

Tags: createjs, easeljs

Pivot of stage is set to `Left Top` corner of canvas but I want `Left Bottom` corner.
So then up is `+y` and right is `+x`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not advisable to transform the stage -- there are some issues with how mouse coordinates are transformed.

1. Put your contents in a Container instead
2. Set the coordinates of the container to the stage width/height
3. Move your contents into negative x/y

If you absolutely must transform your stage, you can set the `regX` and `regY` to the stage width/height. It will move the contents, so you will have to counter-position the contents so they display properly.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sort of... regX, rexY is doing his job, but I still can't get the right XY coordination, because nature of rendering. I think its impossible to have origin at Left Bottom corner and have x and y axis positive. Thanks